# Small percentage of parameters cause very slow queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two tables (in an Azure SQL database):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Action]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Resource] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Action] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Action] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceScope]
(
    [Resource] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Scope] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ResourceScope] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ResourceScope] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Scope] ASC, [Resource] ASC)
```

The `Action` table contains about 15 M actions, regarding about 1.5 M unique resources. The `ResourceScope` table contains about 10K rows with unique resources and one of a couple of different scopes.

An API requires paging through the `Action` table with the following query, where both `<id>` and `<scope>` are variable, but the pages are always the same size.

```sql
SELECT TOP 101
    [Action].[ID], 
    [Action].[Action], 
    [Action].[Resource], 
    [Action].[Timestamp]
FROM 
    [Action] 
JOIN 
    [ResourceScope] ON [ResourceScope].[Resource] = [Action].[Resource] 
WHERE 
    [Action].[ID] <= <id>
    AND [ResourceScope].[Scope] = <scope>
ORDER BY 
    [Action].[ID] DESC
```

When paging through the data for a certain scope about 95% of all queries take about 15ms, but the remaining 5% take anywhere between 500ms and 4000ms. The slow queries use always exactly the same id/scope combination, where I can narrow down to some exact IDs that make the query slow.

The ids for which the query is slow have the exact same query plan as the fast ones, but the slow ones perform a huge amount of clustered index seeks on the `ResourceScope` primary key, where the fast ones only perform a couple of executions (mostly around 100 executions) of that clustered index seek on that index.

Example of a plan for a slow id:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryScGHekR

Example of a plan for a fast id:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1c6MrxyA

When I add an indexed view for a specific scope, like below, and page trough that view, the 5% slow queries disappear.

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DemoSetAction]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS  
    SELECT
        [dbo].[Action].[ID], 
        [dbo].[Action].[Action], 
        [dbo].[Action].[Resource], 
        [dbo].[Action].[Timestamp]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Action] 
    JOIN 
        [dbo].[ResourceScope] ON [dbo].[ResourceScope].[Resource] = dbo.[Action].[Resource] 
    WHERE 
        [dbo].[ResourceScope].[Scope] = 'demo-set'

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_DemoSet ON [dbo].[DemoSetAction] (ID);
```

Paging query on view:

```sql
SELECT TOP 101
    [DemoSetAction].[ID], 
    [DemoSetAction].[Action], 
    [DemoSetAction].[Resource], 
    [DemoSetAction].[Timestamp]
FROM 
    [DemoSetAction] 
WHERE 
    [Action].[ID] <= <id>   
ORDER BY 
    [Action].[ID] DESC
```

Since the scopes can be dynamically added (but are not expected to grow beyond ~25 unique scopes), I would prefer not to make indexed views for every scope.

Two questions:

1. What causes the slow queries?
2. Are there any indexes or other things I could add/change to allow for the same or similar query performance without the use of the indexed views?

Comment: As an FYI (on your `VIEW` `DemoSetAction`'s definition) [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204565/5203)

Comment: @GSerg I found that question before, but unfortunately nothing that is recommended there seems solve or even affect my issue

Comment: Try CTE instead of View. Look at this [article](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch). Offset pagination is used there, and you use keyset, but it might help.

Comment: Can you change your ordering to order by `Resource DESC, Id DESC` then you could add a normal index and get a better join https://dbfiddle.uk/MNCO-7S8

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov There is absolutely no difference between (no-recursive) CTE and view performance in SQL Server.

Comment: In ``slow`` query readed 565474 rows clustered index seek for [PK_ActivityStreamsAction] and 107 rows for ``fast``. Can you show result for ``select avg(cnt),max(cnt),min(cnt) from(select resource ,count(*) cnt from Action)x``

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a columnstore index on the view ?

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Action]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Resource] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Action] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Action] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceScope]
(
    [Resource] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Scope] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ResourceScope] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ResourceScope] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Scope] ASC, [Resource] ASC);
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DemoSetAction]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS  
    SELECT
        A.[ID], 
        A.[Action], 
        A.[Resource], 
        A.[Timestamp],
        R.[Scope]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Action] AS A
    JOIN 
        [dbo].[ResourceScope] AS R ON A.[Resource] = R.[Resource] 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_DemoSet ON [dbo].[DemoSetAction] (ID, [Scope]);
GO
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX XC_DemoSet ON [dbo].[DemoSetAction]  ([ID], [Action], [Resource], [Timestamp], [Scope]);
GO
```